# Where does Role Name gets stored and what is the further use of it?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to send an envelope based on a template to multiple recipients using REST API, where I need to set TemplateRoles to send template to additional users however I need to set RoleName to each Template Role entry. Was wondering where will this role name be used once envelope is created? or is it juts required while setting TemplateRoles? Where can I see Role Name from within an envelope?

Sorry, new to DocuSign :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocuSign Templates are like blue print or re-usable design which will be reused at any time to create new envelopes with new set of recipients. While creating DocuSign Templates, you need to put some `placeholders` for the recipients, these placeholders are called `roleNames`. Now, when you are creating a new envelopes based on the server templates, at that time you will pass the actual value of the recipients like name and email for the roleNames. For instance, in your server templates you have created roleNames like `Buyer` and `Seller` and document used in server template is a seller agreement. Now you want to reuse the template again and again for different set of seller and Buyer, so you will pas the actual values in the envelope based on the `Seller` and `Buyer` roleNames.

Please refer to [Creating Templates](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-working-with-templates) for exploring more details.

API example of using server template will be like below, where 07a2484d-c144-4ad6-a218-85b96bcea4cb is you servertemplateId, `roleName` in the below call should exactly match the one present in the server template, in this case it is `Seller` and `Buyer`:

```
{
    "compositeTemplates": [{
        "compositeTemplateId": "1",
        "inlineTemplates": [{
            "recipients": {
                "signers": [{
                    "email": "selleremail@email.com",
                    "name": "Seller Name",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "roleName": "Seller",
                },
                {
                    "email": "buyeremail@email.com",
                    "name": "Buyer Name",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "roleName": "Buyer",
                }]
            },
            "sequence": "2"
        }],
        "serverTemplates": [{
            "sequence": "1",
            "templateId": "07a2484d-c144-4ad6-a218-85b96bcea4cb"
        }]
    }],
    "emailSubject": "Test flow with Templates",
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Also I would use above Design pattern i.e CompositeTemplate to create an envelope instead of TemplateRole design pattern, as CompositeTemplate has more flexibility and be easily changed for any new usecases down the line in future.